# "launch_template_id" and "launch_template_version" inside "worker_groups_launch_template" block

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-aws, amazon-eks

Is it possible to pass " launch_template_id" and "launch_template_version" inside "worker_groups_launch_template" block or is it allowed only inside a Node Group ?

Even if I pass the Launch Template details, it is still taking some default values (E.g.: Instnce type as m4.large) for the EC2 instance worker nodes.

```
terraform -v
Terraform v1.0.0
on windows_amd64

aws = {
      source = "hashicorp/aws"
      version = "3.50.0"
}

# Launch Template Resource
resource "aws_launch_template" "eks_launch_template" {
  
  name = "${local.name_prefix}-eks-launch-template"
  description = "EKS Launch Template"
  
  update_default_version = true

  # Root Volume
  block_device_mappings {
    device_name = "/dev/xvda"
    ebs {   
      volume_size = var.eks_worker_root_volume_size
      volume_type = var.eks_worker_root_volume_type
      delete_on_termination = true
    }
  }

  ebs_optimized = true    
  instance_type = var.eks_worker_instance_type      
  key_name = var.eks_worker_key_pair       
  monitoring {
    enabled = true
  }

  network_interfaces {
    associate_public_ip_address = false
    delete_on_termination       = true
  }

  tag_specifications {
    resource_type = "instance"
    tags = local.tags
  }
}

module "eks" {

    source  = "terraform-aws-modules/eks/aws"
    version = "17.1.0"
       
    cluster_name    = local.eks_cluster_name
    cluster_version = var.eks_cluster_version

    vpc_id          = module.vpc.vpc_id
    subnets         = module.vpc.private_subnets

    worker_groups_launch_template = [

        {
            name                 = "worker-group-1"
            asg_desired_capacity = var.eks_worker_nodes   
            asg_min_size         = var.eks_worker_nodes     
            asg_max_size         = var.eks_worker_nodes 

            launch_template_id = aws_launch_template.eks_launch_template.id
            launch_template_version = aws_launch_template.eks_launch_template.latest_version
        }
    ]


    cluster_endpoint_private_access = true

    write_kubeconfig  = true
    kubeconfig_output_path = "./kubeconfig/"

    tags = local.tags

}
```

If it is not supported, is there any way to define an additional ebs volume ?

Comment: Does your `eks_launch_template` actually define instance type? it is not shown in your question what `eks_launch_template` is.

Comment: @Marcin : Yes I have passed t3.micro in my Launch Template.

Comment: From https://github.com/terraform-aws-modules/terraform-aws-eks/blob/master/local.tf, it looks like those two parameters you're asking about are supported there. I haven't used this module though, so don't have a solid answer for you sorry

Comment: ` aws_launch_template.eks_launch_template.id` is not a module, but you are linking to some module.

Comment: @Marcin : No it is a Resource. I have added the Launch Template details as well. Please have a look.